# ResultSet is Closed

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Following is my Table Definition:

```
create Table alarms(
         alarmId int primary key identity(1,1),
         alarmDate varchar(50) not null,
         alarmText varchar(50) not null,
         alarmStatus varchar(10) Check (alarmStatus in(-1, 0, 1)) Default 0
         );
```

Secondly here are some of my methods i'm using:

```
public void restartDatabase(){
try{
        Class.forName(Settings.getDatabaseDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection( Settings.getJdbcUrl() );
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}


public ResultSet executeQuery(String query){
ResultSet result = null;
try {
    result = statement.executeQuery(query); 
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
return result;          
}

public void closeDatabase() {
try {
  if ((statement != null) && (connection != null)) {    
      statement.close();
      connection.close();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
```

What i want to do is to get all the alarmId's from the table where date is equal to the given date and then against each alarmId i want to update its status to given status:

```
public static void updateAlarmStatus(int status) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    database.restartDatabase();
    try {
        rs = database
                .executeQuery("Select alarmId from alarms where alarmDate = '"
                        + Alarm.getFormattedDateTime(DateFormat.FULL,
                                DateFormat.SHORT) + "'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            database.executeUpdate("update alarms set alarmStatus = '"+status+"' where alarmId = '"+rs.getString("alarmId")+"'");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        database.closeDatabase();
    }
}
```

But it generates the Error that Result Set is Closed.
I Goggled it and came to know that a result set automatically closes when we try to execute another query inside it
and it needs to restart the connection.
i tried calling restartDatabase() method that is creating new connection but still getting the same error.

Comment: Does `database.executeUpdate()` use the same `Statement` instance as the `executeQuery()` method? You also don't need two statements for this. As far as I can tell, a simple `update alarms set alarmStatus = 1 where alarmDate = '2014-08-17';` will do the same thing. Also look into prepared statements. You are wide open for SQL injection. And finally (but equally important): do ***NOT*** store dates in `VARCHAR` columns, just don't.

Comment: I think you declared connection and statement as instance variable and somewhere the statement gets closed before executeUpdate happens.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing around Connection, Statement or ResultSet like that. To restart your Connection you don't need to reload the Driver class. And once you re-connect you would have to re-run your query. Finally, you seem to have a number of other issues in your code. I would suggest you find a tutorial on JDBC or switch to an ORM tool.

Comment: What are the issues dear?

Comment: what do you mean by  " To restart your Connection you don't need to reload the Driver class. And once you re-connect you would have to re-run your query. " ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i took your advice which was:
    "do NOT store dates in VAR CHAR columns, just don't."
I've decided to use the Apache derby instead of SQL.
please guide me what is the Data Type for Date Time in derby and also tell me how to set date format there?

Comment: The data types are all documented in the manual: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/crefsqlj31068.html#crefsqlj31068 `date` or `timestamp` columns do ***NOT*** have "a format". You apply formatting when you _display_ such a value in your application, but the values are stored ***without*** a format

Comment: In Microsoft SQL we have to set format to the dates using set DateFormate function, how can i store dates with the following formate in apache derby: "Wednesday, August 2014, 11:30 PM"

Comment: I've googled alot but i can't find what editor i should use to practice java db, as we use Management studio for Microsoft SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also select and change all alarmIds at once:

```
rs = database.
    executeQuery("Select group_concat(distinct alarmId) as alarmIds from alarms group by alarmDate having alarmDate = '"
                        + Alarm.getFormattedDateTime(DateFormat.FULL,
                                DateFormat.SHORT) + "'");
while (rs.next()) { // there will be only one result
    database.executeUpdate("update alarms set alarmStatus = '"+status+"' where alarmId in ("+rs.getString("alarmIds")+")");
}
```

Comment: what is group_concat(alarmId) ?

Comment: MySQL function to aggregate the values of a certain field into a comma-separated string http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: made one small change, in case you have repeating alarmId values for the same date

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing executeUpdate uses the same instance variable for its Statement as the query uses. When you create a new Statement and assign it to the variable, nothing is referring to the old one, so it gets cut loose and becomes subject to garbage-collection. During garbage collection the statement's finalizer is invoked, closing it. Closing the statement makes the ResultSet it created close as well.

You shouldn't be sharing these Statement variables between different queries and updates. The statement should be a local variable and not a member of an object instance.

Also, result Sets should always be local variables, they shouldn't be passed outside the method where they're created. The resultSet is a reference to a cursor, it doesn't actually hold any data. Always have your code read from the resultSet and populate some data structure with the results, then return the data structure.

Comment: Thanku so much and i understand everything now except some of your lines :

The resultSet is a reference to a cursor, it doesn't actually hold any data. Always have your code read from the resultSet and populate some data structure with the results, then return the data structure.